# java.sql.SQLException [Microsoft] [ODBC SQL Server Driver] [SQL Server] Invalid object name 'table name'

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

When I connect Java to Mssql using JDBC ODBC driver

```
try 
{
    ps=conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE products SET stock=? WHERE id=?");

    ps.setInt(1, prods.getStock());
    ps.setInt(2, prods.getId());

    int b = ps.executeUpdate();

    if(b!=0)
    {
        System.out.println("success");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Fail");
    } 
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

This catch block rises this exception

```
java.sql.SQLException [Microsoft] [ODBC SQL Server Driver]
  [SQL Server] Invalid object name 'products'
```

I am working on this part from last 2 days. How I will solve this exception?

Comment: are you sure that you have table products in your database?

Comment: try UPDATE [products] and see if it works

Comment: Maybe you selected a wrong DB? Can you show how the connection is created?

Comment: yes i am sure my database having products table

Comment: i already used that UPDATE[products] i am getting the same error

Comment: Try `UPDATE DatabaseName.dbo.Products` or `DatabaseName.MySchema.Products` as the case may be. If it works, then you are connecting to the wrong database and/or schema. If it doesn't work then you have either a permissions problem or the wrong server. FYI, it is considered important to always specify schema and object name in all SQL statements, i.e. `UPDATE dbo.TableName SET ...`

Answer (score 5):

This error message is thrown when the table can't be found. That can have several reasons:

- you are connecting to a different DB
- the table was deleted
- the table is in another DB schema
- your user does not have read permissions on that table any more

Comment: table is exists and database is also same , but still it is giving error.

Comment: here i am using windows authentication is there any problem with that?

Comment: @pardhu: Does your windows user have rights in your MSSQL Server? You can check that if you connect with that user to your DB using MS SQL Studio and try to browse the table you need.

Comment: i am browsing that table and watching those data is all possible, then which rights i need here?

Comment: @pardhu: Could you show your connection string? Also are you sure that the table is in the default schema of your user?

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine that your connection string has no default database - you are probably connecting to 'master' in which case the above won't work

You can test this by qualifying your query with the database and schema name:

e.g.

```
ps=conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE [YourDatabaseName].[schema].products SET stock=? WHERE id=?");
```

put your values in where needed (standard default schema is 'dbo' eg. ProductsDatabase.dbo.products)

If this works then your connection string is incorrect

Comment: i write using this query "master.dbo.products" here also i am getting same error.please help me

Comment: Is the product table in the 'master' database or another database? I would expect that you created a new database for the table, in which case you should not put master.dbo.products but <productsdatabasename>.dbo.products - can you show your connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this exception is thrown if the table does not exist, or that there is an error with the connection string. Maybe not connecting to the correct database?

Comment: here i am using windows authentication is there any problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue. Cause of the issue in my case was the user running the report has the DEFAULT_DATABASE  pointing to the master database, after changing it to the right database it was able to locate the object.

Thanks